# navigation bar arrow not showing under each tab CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to use css to get an arrow that points down from each tab of the navigation bar. This is what I have so far.

```css
ul {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
}

li {
   float: left;
}

li a {
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 16px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
}

li a:visited {
   color: white;
}

li a:hover {
   color: #df9fa2;
}

#menu a:hover:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 52px;
   width: 0px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -15px;
   border-left: 15px solid transparent;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
   border-top: 15px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">      
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a class="link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The arrow is always showing up in the middle of the navigation bar. This is because of the `left: 50%` code. I think it's doing this because it's getting 50% from the wrong element but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be great.

Comment: There is your code from the article above ... where you have arrow? .. i cant see it (https://jsfiddle.net/okcbpaj6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning can sometimes be a little tricky. You need to position the parent (`<a>`: `position: relative;`), so that the positioning of the arrow is calculated relative to the link.

To set the arrows down under the bar, you have to use `bottom` minus the height of the arrow: `bottom: -15px;`. I had to remove your `overflow:hidden;` and put an element with `clear:both;` after the `<li>` tags, to make them visible, because your `<ul>`s height was zero with only containing floating elements.

```css
ul {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-in;
  position: relative;
}
li a:visited {
  color: white;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #df9fa2;
}
#menu a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right;"><a class="link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just read some examples about positioning in CSS:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: what if I want the arrow below the bar instead of above it?